# Linear Programming: Maximize

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Jimbo Enterprises produces $n$ products. Each product can be produced in one of $m$ machines. Let $t_{ij}$ be the time in hours needed to produce one unit of product $i$ on machine $j$. For month $k$, the number of hours available on machine $j$ is $h_{kj}$. Customers are willing to buy up to $d_{ik}$ of product $i$ in month $k$ at the unit cost of $c_{ik}$. Formulate a Linear Program that Jimbo can use to maximize the revenue by selling the products for the next $p$ months.

I need help making a formulation for this Linear Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unknowns:**

Let $x_{ijk}$ be the units of product $i$ produced on machine $j$ in month $k$.

This can be folded into a vector of dimension $N = n\,m\,p$.

**Cost function:**
$$
c^\top x  = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=k_0}^{k_0 + p - 1} c_{ik} x_{ijk}
$$

**Constraints:**

1.) Available production time on machine $j$ for month $k$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n t_{ij} x_{ijk} \le h_{kj} \quad (j \in \{ 1, \dotsc, m \}, k \in \{ k_0, \dotsc, k_0 + p -1 \})
$$
These are $m \, p$ inequalities.

2.) Demand for month $k$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m x_{ijk} \le d_{ik} \quad (i \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}, k \in \{ k_0, \dotsc, k_0 + p -1 \})
$$
These are $n \, p$ inequalities.

Depending on what form your problem should be, you might need to add constraints $x_{ijk} \ge 0$ and introduce slack variables, if you need equalities instead of inequalities.

If "unit cost $c_{ik}$" means that this is the revenue for product $i$ in month $k$ (and not the production cost), then one maximizes the cost function. Otherwise one would need additional information.